# jqGrid: Set custom header before Edit only

Tags: jqgrid, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I need to set a custom http header before 'Edit' (PUT) only. 
I tried the loadBeforeSend as mentioned here - [How to set request header to the ajax object for jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706579/how-to-set-request-header-to-the-ajax-object-for-jqgrid/5706690#5706690)

```
loadBeforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
                alert('loadBeforeSend');
                jqXHR.setRequestHeader('If-Match', '*');
            },
```

But this function gets invoked before every request. I need this header to be set only on a 'PUT' request but not on any other. My 'GET' request actually fails with this header.

How do I check if it is a PUT or a GET inside the loadBeforeSend ? or is there another way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't wrote which [editing mode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#editing) you use which is really important to get an exact answer on your question. In general jqGrid provide option `ajaxRowOptions`, `ajaxEditOptions`, `ajaxCellOptions` etc which allow you to customize [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) calls which makes jqGrid internally. One can use `beforeSend` callback of [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to make customization which you require. By the way jqGrid uses the callback internally for loading of the grid and it calls `loadBeforeSend` callback if it exist. Other Ajax calls made by jqGrid don't use `beforeSend` callback and so you have no callback like `loadBeforeSend`.

So you should just specify `beforeSend` callback which do the same what you want to do inside of `loadBeforeSend` callback, but you need place `beforeSend` inside of `ajaxRowOptions`, `ajaxEditOptions`, `ajaxCellOptions` and so on depend on editing mode which you use. You can find example of such implementations in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11992420/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6477061/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10287508/315935) and [some another answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:315935%20beforeSend).

Comment: I am trying the inline edit mode. I guess I need to use the 'beforeSend' inside of 'ajaxRowOptions'